# Store parameters of implies() function in z3

Tags: c++, z3, smt

I want to create a function that can store the left and the right parameters of implies() function in 2 different expression variables. 
Solution with code is highly appreciable. 
Thank you.

This is something I had tried before.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "z3++.h"
using namespace z3;
using namespace std;

void walk(int tab, expr e)
{
    string blanks(tab, ' ');

    if(e.is_const())
    {
        cout << blanks << "ARGUMENT: " << e << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << blanks << "APP: " << e.decl().name() << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < e.num_args(); i++)
        {
            walk(tab + 5, e.arg(i));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    context c;
    expr x = c.bool_const("x");
    expr y = c.bool_const("y");
    expr z = c.bool_const("z");
    expr e = implies(z,(x && y));
    walk(0, e);
}
```

and this was the output:

```
APP: =>
     ARGUMENT: z
     APP: and
          ARGUMENT: x
          ARGUMENT: y
```

Comment: Well, the [documentation](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1expr.html) says that `expr` supports an `is_implies()` method, and furthermore there is an `arg(i)` method to extract the i'th argument. Did you try those?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Your output appears to be correct, so you seem to have determined the arguments just fine. What is it that you are stuck on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use arg() function from z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455502/how-to-use-arg-function-from-z3)

Comment: @alias That question was posed by the same author. (note that the little amount of code here comes from that answer!) I can only assume the author is unwilling or incapable of reading the documentation and trying things for themself.

Comment: @Botje that does appear to be the case, hence my vote for closure.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just make my comment explicit by means of an example:

```
if (e.is_implies()) {
    cout << "left side: " <<endl;
    walk(4, e.arg(0));
    cout << "right side: " <<endl;
    walk(4, e.arg(1));
}
```

This uses the `is_implies` and `arg` methods of the `expr` class. [documentation](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1expr.html)

Comment: so can I conclude from this that every expression has atmax only 2 arguments?

Comment: No, only that the implies operator has exactly two arguments. You should read the documentation to find out the shapes of other predicates.

Comment: And right below `implies` in the documentation I linked to is `ite`, which has three arguments, and then there's `mk_or` which has a variable number of arguments. If you cannot find out from the documentation, you can always run your program in a debugger and look at the resulting `expr`.