# How to export a Z3_ast to binary and how to search one for func names?

Tags: python, c++, z3, symbolic-math

In the project that I'm working on, I need to do two things using Z3 C++ API:

- export a Z3_ast to a binary buffer
- search a Z3_ast if it contains a symbol declaration inside.

How I do this currently: I'm converting the Z3_ast to string then load it again where I need it. The search is done by string search.
I think there is a more efficient way to handle the problem. A python API solution would also be helpful since I can track the CPP code that implements it.

Comment: The answer boils down to "walk the AST": write a recursive process that interrogates a node kind and then walks its children, if any.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to understand if this kind of API exists already, or do I need to recompile the source code and live with code divergences.

Comment: There are accessor functions for poking at AST nodes, but you will have to write the AST walk yourself. There is a small example in the [Z3 distribution](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp#L805-L824) to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to walk down the AST and pick out the nodes. the Z3 API provides all the necessary recognizers. Note that serializing the AST into a string and doing a string search is not only slow, it would also be very error-prone should they change how the surface syntax is represented.

There was a similar question a while ago, you might want to look at the answer there to get at least a starting point: [How to use arg() function from z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455502/how-to-use-arg-function-from-z3/56466305#56466305)

Comment: I understand now how to search efficiently for arguments. But how can I serialize the Z3_AST to a buffer ? E.g I want to send a Z3_AST over the network. Walking the tree and doing my own serialization/deserialization seems to be a little error prone...

Comment: If you have a solver object `s = Solver()`, then `s.sexpr()` will give you an s-expression rendering of all the constraints in it that you can ship to anywhere you want. This is rather crude, but is quite effective!